# how to pass parameter to camel custom datafotmat?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am new to camel

i have implemented custom dataformat

**Now i want to use custom property in marshel or unmarshal method.**

Is this possible to do this in camel?

please give example if there is any way.

My custom dataformat code is as follows

```
package com.camel.spring.test.dataFormat;

import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import com.predic8.wsdl.Definitions;
import com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser;
import com.predic8.wstool.creator.RequestCreator;
import com.predic8.wstool.creator.SOARequestCreator;

public final class SOAPDataFormat implements DataFormat {

    public void marshal(Exchange exchange, Object dataDefination, OutputStream stream) throws Exception {
            WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();
            Definitions wsdl = parser
                    .parse("http://localhost:8081/Myservice/services/TestService?wsdl");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            HashMap<String, Object> formParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            SOARequestCreator creator = new SOARequestCreator(wsdl,
                    new RequestCreator(), new MarkupBuilder(writer));
            creator.setBuilder(new MarkupBuilder(writer));
            creator.setDefinitions(wsdl);
            creator.setFormParams(formParams);
            creator.setCreator(new RequestCreator());
            creator.createRequest("TestService", "getApplication","TestServiceHttpBinding");
            stream.write(writer.toString().getBytes());
        }

        public Object unmarshal(Exchange exchange, InputStream stream) throws Exception {
            return null;
        }
}
```

my route configuration is

```
<camel:route>
        <from uri="file:d:/inbox/wsJson?noop=true" />
        <marshal >
            <custom ref="soapDataFormat" />
        </marshal>
        <to uri="cxf://http://localhost:8081/Myservice/services/TestService?wsdlURL=http://localhost:8081//Myservice/services/TestService?wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://service.application.atpl.com}TestService&amp;portName={http://service.application.atpl.com}TestServiceHttpPort&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
    </camel:route>
```

I am just working on marshaling so ignore unmarshal code.

i want to pass `"http://localhost:8081/Myservice/services/TestService?wsdl","TestService", "getApplication","TestServiceHttpBinding"` values runtime that is changed on request to request basis.

i found one work around by setting header values, but which is not proper solution

please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, you should do it by setting header values, so you `SOAPDataFormat` stay *immutable*. You should also consider to create a object with all variables your want and set it as just one header variable.

Comment: @MilanBaran yes that's the solution i got initially.

Comment: I would use the content enricher pattern, see https://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Comment: @Peter Thanks,  i used enrich, i solved this issue.